# JavaScript orientation beta offset WebGL

Tags: javascript, three.js, accelerometer, gyroscope

I've been stuck on this problem for ages. Unfortunately I've not had success in my searches across Google / Stack. Totally stumped.

The crux of the problem is **adjusting** the **beta** value that is returned from the `deviceorientation`event in JavaScript.

What I want to do is adjust the beta value to **equal 0** when the phone is held **upright**. I've tried to compensate the value by reducing beta by both positive and negative integers of 90 as well as use a integer of 0 and adding a reduced `event.beta` value; all to no avail.

The idea behind the concept is using the gyroscope to orientate the THREE.js camera / object within a panorama. When you tilt the phone up, you look up, down equals down and holding it level results in you looking forward. I've tried using some of the plugins out there (namely the one by mrdoob and threex), but their motion doesn't seem to work, unfortunately. There is a weird Z axis rotation that spins the scene rather than pans it in mrdoobs example and threex sets the level position to be when the phone is held flat, rather than upright.

Any suggestions on the maths here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the Google Cardboard examples? [At the bottom of this pages are links to code for three.js](https://vr.chromeexperiments.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate it. I went to the pages you linked and for some reason I still have the same problem. Their camera orientation is unfortunately still not calibrated correctly. I'm starting to wonder if it's my phone. I'm using a Sony Xperia Z running Android latest OS / Chrome like. What is the experience on your phone / tablet?

Comment: I don't have that much experience yet. Maybe this will help? https://github.com/dorukeker/gyronorm.js or this https://github.com/borismus/webvr-boilerplate

Comment: Thanks for sharing your links. I'll try those out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi again @gman. I'm doing some testing now. It seems to be working "stablish" with the cardboard example across iOS and Android. I have a feeling it's just the state of WebVR at this point on mobile; especially mine. Feel free to post your links as the answer so I can accept it. :)